# Lambda - if anyMatch do something orElse do something

Tags: java, lambda, java-8

Can I do this all logic with using one lambda expression?

```
boolean isTrue = myList.stream().anyMatch( m -> m.getName().equals("a") );         
         
if (isTrue) { do something } 
else { do other thing }
```

Comment: The code you provided does not even compile. Beside that it's not quiet clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I want to learn that can I continue the lamda expression after anyMatch. Like list.stream(),anyMatch(true).do(dosomething).orElse(dosomething);

Comment: `anyMatch()` returns a primitive `boolean`, so you obviously can not continue the lambda expression.

Comment: You can cheat your way around using `filter(e -> /*condition*/).findAny().ifPresent(e -> /*consumer*/)`. However, there is no `orElse`.

Comment: The lambda can do almost whatever you want it to do -- on a per-element basis -- before it returns a `boolean` (as `Stream.anyMatch()` requires).  The ultimate result of `anyMatch()` itself is necessarily outside the scope of the lambda passed as its argument.

Comment: cool one but I cannot do Else in this way.

Comment: filter(e -> /*condition*/).findAny().ifPresent(e -> /*consumer*/) ifNotPresent?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Since Java 9 `Optional` class added

[`public void ifPresentOrElse​(Consumer<? super T> action, Runnable emptyAction)`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Optional.html#ifPresentOrElse(java.util.function.Consumer,java.lang.Runnable))

Also instead of `anyMatch(<<yourCondition>>)` which returns `boolean` you can use `filter(<<yourCondition>>).findAny()` which returns `Optional`.

So you can combine it and write code like

```
yourStream
    .filter(m -> m.getName().equals("a")) //your condition
    .findAny() //returns Optional
    .ifPresentOrElse(
        // action when value exists 
        value -> System.out.println("There was a value "+value),

        // action when there was no value
        () -> System.out.println("No value found")
    );
```

Comment: I don’t see, how this relates to `anyMatch`, which returns a `boolean`. Besides, it wouldn’t be an improvement over a simple `if(myList.stream().anyMatch(m -> m.getName().equals("a"))) { do something } else { do something other }` anyway.

Comment: @Holger I tried to clarify my answer a little. Anyway since as you mentioned `anyMatch` returns boolean I suspect that it was used only as an example and *main* question/intention is more along "how to express `if(valueInStream){ handleValue } else { doSomethingElse }` with stream/lambda?". I can't disagree with `if(myList.stream().anyMatch(m -> m.getName().equals("a"))) { do something } else { do something other }` being simpler, but in cases where stream is more complex ending it with `.ifPresentOrElse(MyClass::handleValue, MyClass::handleLackOfValue)` could also be reasonable.

Comment: Well, yes, if the value is needed, `.findAny().ifPresentOrElse(…)` is a reasonable choice. But then, the question’s example would have been poorly chosen.