# Layered filtering using Java Stream API

Tags: java, java-stream

I have some imperative Java conditional code that I want to refactor to use Streams.

Specifically, I have this map that I want to filter into a List based on specific filter criteria.

```
private  Map<Integer,Thing> thingMap = new HashMap<Integer,Thing>();
// populate thingMap
```

And here's the code that uses it:

```
List<Thing> things = new ArrayList<Thing>();

for (Thing thing : thingMap.values()) {
    if (thing.getCategory().equals(category)) {
        if (location == null) {
            things.add(thing);
        } else if (thing.getLocation().equals(location)) {
            things.add(thing);
        }
    }
}
```

I refactored that to the following. But what's missing is I want the location to be checked *only* if the category filter passes. Also, I suspect there's a better way to do this:

```
List<Thing> things = thingMap.entrySet()
                      .stream()
                      .filter(t -> t.getValue().getCategory().equals(category))
                      .filter(t -> 
                          location == null || 
                          t.getValue().getLocation().equals(location)
                       )
                      .map(Map.Entry::getValue)
                      .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

What would be the idiomatic approach to retaining the layered conditional checks using Streams?

Comment: The stream operations are invoked sequentially same as any other code, so second and third filters will **only** be invoked if the category filter passes, or am I missing the point?  Also surely the second filter should be **not equal** to null?

Comment: Your current approach will throw a `NullPointerException`. You should write `t.getValue().getLocation() != null`

Comment: @Arvind, but I believe that's the opposite of the filter I want (compared to the existing code).

Comment: @sridecolossus, so maybe my refactored code is already the equivalent of the prior code.

Comment: @JWoodchuck - The filter, `t.getValue().getLocation() == null` will return those values for which location is `null` and therefore the next filter, `t.getValue().getLocation().equals(location)` will throw a `NullPointerException`.

Comment: @Arvind, makes sense - just wondering how to remedy that.

Comment: @JWoodchuck No I don't think so, it will fail as it stands for the reason that @Arvind stated.  Perhaps you're looking for `t -> (t.getValue().getLocation() == null) || (t.getValue().getLocation().equals(location))`?  which is essentially what your imperative code does.

Comment: Does it answer your question? [Lambda - if anyMatch do something orElse do something](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56203286/lambda-if-anymatch-do-something-orelse-do-something)

Comment: @Arvind The second filter does seem weird (== null), but that's how it stands in the existing code.

Comment: I made an edit and I believe, based on this feedback, my new code now matches the existing code. I.e., if the category filter is not passed then the location won't get checked anyway. Thanks!!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Operations chained after a `filter` will only be executed for elements accepted by the predicate. So there is no need to worry about that.

You could also join the conditions into a single `filter` step, just like you could join the nested `if` statements into a single `if`, by combining the conditions using `&&`. The result is the same.

But note that the loop uses the condition `location == null`, referring to the variable declared outside the code snippet you have posted, not `thing.getLocation() == null`.

Besides that, you made other unnecessary changes compared to the loop. The loop iterates over the `values()` view of the map whereas you used `entrySet()` for the Stream instead, introducing the need to call `getValue()` on a `Map.Entry` four times.

A straight-forward translation of the loop logic is much simpler:

```java
List<Thing> things = thingMap.values().stream()
    .filter(thing -> thing.getCategory().equals(category))
    .filter(thing -> location == null || thing.getLocation().equals(location))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```